# Control main thread with multiple Future jobs in scala

Tags: scala, list, elasticsearch, scala-collections, scalatest

```
def fixture =
    new {

      val xyz = new XYZ(spark)
    }    
val fList: scala.collection.mutable.MutableList[scala.concurrent.Future[Dataset[Row]]] = scala.collection.mutable.MutableList[scala.concurrent.Future[Dataset[Row]]]() //mutable List of future means List[Future]

    test("test case") {     
        val tasks = for (i <- 1 to 10) {
          fList ++ scala.collection.mutable.MutableList[scala.concurrent.Future[Dataset[Row]]](Future {
            println("Executing task " + i )
            val ds = read(fixture.etlSparkLayer,i)           
            ds
          })
        }

        Thread.sleep(1000*4200)
        val futureOfList = Future.sequence(fList)//list of Future job in Future sequence       
        println(Await.ready(futureOfList, Duration.Inf))


        val await_result: Seq[Dataset[Row]] = Await.result(futureOfList, Duration.Inf)
        println("Squares: " + await_result)

        futureOfList.onComplete {
          case Success(x) => println("Success!!! " + x)
          case Failure(ex) => println("Failed !!! " + ex)
        }               
      }
```

I am executing one test case with sequence of Future List and List have collection of Future.I trying to execute same fuction multiple time parallely by help of using Future in scala.In my system only 4 job start in one time after completion of 4 jobs next 4 job will starting like that complete all the jobs. So how to start more than 4 job at a time and how main Thread will wait to complete all the Future thread ? I tried **Await.result** and **Await.ready** but not able to control main thread , for main thread control i m use Thread.sleep concept.this program is for read from RDBMS table and write in Elasticsearch. So how to control main thread main issue?

Comment: Do you have to use futures?  Actors seem like a better fit.  You can control concurrency much easier with actors.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29344430/scala-waiting-for-sequence-of-futures. Anyway, I´ve had many problems with Scala Futures trying to control their execution. I had to use Scalaz Task and everything worked much better.

Comment: @JonAnderson I know that but for that we may have 2 add some dependency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you use the `scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global` `ExecutionContext` you can tune the number of threads as described here:

https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/library/scala/concurrent/impl/ExecutionContextImpl.scala#L100

Specifically the following System Properties: `scala.concurrent.context.minThreads`, `scala.concurrent.context.numThreads`. `scala.concurrent.context.maxThreads`, and `scala.concurrent.context.maxExtraThreads`

Otherwise, you can rewrite your code to something like this:

```
import scala.collection.immutable
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent._
import java.util.concurrent.Executors

test("test case") { 
  implicit val ec = ExecutionContext.fromExecutorService(ExecutorService.newFixedThreadPool(NUMBEROFTHREADSYOUWANT))
  val aFuture = Future.traverse(1 to 10) {
    i => Future {
      println("Executing task " + i)
      read(fixture.etlSparkLayer,i) // If this is a blocking operation you may want to consider wrapping it in a `blocking {}`-block.          
    }
  }
  aFuture.onComplete(_ => ec.shutdownNow()) // Only for this test, and to make sure the pool gets cleaned up
  val await_result: immutable.Seq[Dataset[Row]] = Await.result(aFuture, 60.minutes) // Or other timeout
  println("Squares: " + await_result) 
}
```

Comment: I m beginner in Scala so can u please send me some link or material or tips to my mail sahoorakesh558@gmail.com

Comment: by this i can control number of there from thread pool but how to control spark context operation ? Means i am trying to write in ES by help of spark , But spark is start writing only 4 at a time.

Comment: @xyz_scala That is not a question for me to answer.