# How to correctly handle individual exceptions in Future.sequence?

Tags: scala

Suppose I have an application that downloads files from a server and uploads them to another server.

The downloading files do not necessarily exist on the server.

So, when the file does not exist, I want to skip it, not to proceed to upload it and make sure that only existing files are downloaded/uploaded.
(i.e. no single downloading exception should stop all other downloading and uploading processes)

The Future should be either successful with no results(Unit) or failure with exception along with the failed path.

What is the standard way to handle this situation?

```
def downloadFile(path: String): Future[DownloadFile]
def uploadFile(file: DownloadFile): Future[Unit]


Future.sequence(
  paths.map { path =>
    for {
      downloadedFile <- downloadFile(path)
      _ <- uploadFile(downloadedFile)
    } yield Unit
  }
)
```

Comment: When `downloadFile` doesn't find a file, then how does it signal it? It's just failed Future? And what is the exception?

Comment: If not found, no further action needs to be taken. simply skip the file and move on to the next

Comment: But how do you know file doesn't exist?

Comment: The server returns 404. you can assume that when the file not found, some exception is thrown

Comment: What if there are multiple failures? If you use `Future.sequence()` then you get only one `Failure` for the entire set of down/up attempts.

Comment: if there is a better way to handle this case, any suggestions are welcome :)

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29344937/334519

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider

```
  val listOfFutures = List(
    Future(1),
    Future(throw new RuntimeException("path/foo")),
    Future(2),
    Future(throw new RuntimeException("path/bar")),
  )

  Future.traverse(listOfFutures)(_.transform {
    case Success(v) => Try(Some(v))
    case Failure(e) => Try(None)
  }).map(_.flatten) andThen { case v => println(v) }
```

which outputs

```
Success(List(1, 2))
```

Note `Future.sequence` is a simpler version of `Future.traverse`.

---

Applying the comment, consider inverting flattening like so

```
Future.traverse(listOfFutures)(_.transform {
    case Success(v) => Try(None)
    case Failure(e) => Try(Some(e.getMessage))
  }).map { results =>
    if (results.flatten.nonEmpty) throw new RuntimeException(s"Bad paths: ${results.flatten.mkString(",")}")
    else ()
  } andThen { case v => println(v) }
```

which outputs

```
Failure(java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad paths: path/foo,path/bar)
```

Comment: Nice, except, doesn't the OP want the opposite: a list of failures (successes ignored)?

Comment: Ah apologies, I misunderstood the question. Please see edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Either`

```
Future.sequence(
    Seq("path1", "path2").map { path =>
      (for {
        downloadedFile <- downloadFile(path)
        _ <- uploadFile(downloadedFile)
      } yield Right(Unit))
        .recover { case ex: Exception => Left(ex) }
    }
  )
```

This returns  `List(Right(object scala.Unit), Left(java.lang.Exception: Bad path))`

Or the same with `Option`:

```
Future.sequence(
    Seq("path1", "path2").map { path =>
      (for {
        downloadedFile <- downloadFile(path)
        _ <- uploadFile(downloadedFile)
      } yield None)
        .recover { case ex: Exception => Some(ex) }
    }
  )
```

Returns `List(None, Some(java.lang.Exception: Bad path))`

The List can be filtered then.